# how to use last() function in where clause in mysql

Tags: php, sql

How to use `LAST()` function in where clause in *MYSQL*. Is there retrieve the values of last row using Last function.Please anybody help me.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE item = (SELECT LAST(item) FROM table1);
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY id DESC If your table contains incrementing primary key then you can  retrieve the last item by id

Comment: @baseer Ahmed if my coloumn id have random numbers but i have to retrieve the last two rows from the table using that id.